# How can I display different code if my posts table is empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am here because I am trying to display my blog data on the landing page however, I just cleared the testing and now it gives me a NoMethodError. Obviously it's cause the posts table is empty.

I am curious if there is anyway to display static code when the database table is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do.

Suppose you have a `User` model backed by `users` table,then you can check

```
User.any?
```

It returns `true` when you have any record in `users` table and return `false` when you do not have any record.

You can have a condition like this in your code:

```
if User.any?
    #when table in not empty
else
   #your static code when table is empty
end
```

Comment: Life saver! I was so confused. I tried doing one method on an another page and it didn't work! Thank you!

Comment: @Ethan glad it helped you! :)